# How to use sshtunnel module in python and get multiple connections?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, paramiko, ssh-tunnel

I have the following SSH tunneling code with `sshtunnel` lib in python and `openSSH v2` on my Ubuntu 14 server. the problem is, the maximum connections over the tunnel is limited to 1 or 2, and when IDM attempts to establish third and fourth, ... connections, gets failed with this error `Could not establish connection from ('127.0.0.1', 8080) to remote side of the tunnel`

Besides I have Squid3 installed on my server for HTTP proxy.

  **My code:**

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import time
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
'server_ip_address',
ssh_username="user",
ssh_password="password",
local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 8080),
remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3128),
)

server.start()

print(server.local_bind_port)  # show assigned local port
# work with `SECRET SERVICE` through `server.local_bind_port`.
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
server.stop()
```

Comment: did you find any fix for doing more than 2-3 tunnel connections using ssh tunnel module in python? For now, I am just using `ssh -nl` command.